# How Do I solve the problem of Oracle deleting data at a specific time？

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

My SQL statement is as follows：
`delete from "result" where DATA_DATE < TO_DATE('2023-04-06 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS')`  
the error message is：
`ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`
What should I do?

This is part of the information in the table：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bleRw.png)

Comment: What is the datatype of `DATA_DATE`?

Answer (score 3):

If the `DATA_DATE` column is stored as a `DATE` data type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "result" (data_date DATE);

INSERT INTO "result" (data_date)
VALUES (TO_DATE('2023-04-05 12:34:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS'));
```

Then your query works:

```sql
delete from "result"
where DATA_DATE < TO_DATE('2023-04-06 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS');
```

> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

---

If your `DATA_DATE` column is a string data type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "result" (data_date VARCHAR2(19));

INSERT INTO "result" (data_date) VALUES ('2023-04-05 12:34:56');
```

Then your query:

```sql
delete from "result"
where DATA_DATE < TO_DATE('2023-04-06 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS');
```

Is comparing a string to a date and Oracle will implicitly convert the string to a date so that it compares the same data types and the query is effectively:

```sql
delete from "result"
where TO_DATE(
        DATA_DATE,
        (SELECT value FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
      )
      < TO_DATE('2023-04-06 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS');
```

If the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter matches:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Then the query works.

But if the session parameter does not match:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY';
```

Then you may get the error:

> ```
> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
> ```

---

To solve the problem, either:

1. Always store dates in a `DATE` data type (and not as strings).
2. Do not compare different data types as Oracle will perform an implicit type conversion so that it can compare them.

   - Either compare both sides as strings:

     ```sql
     delete from "result"
     where DATA_DATE < '2023-04-06 00:00:00';
     ```
   - Or compare both sides as dates:

     ```sql
     delete from "result"
     where TO_DATE(data_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
           < TO_DATE('2023-04-06 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
     ```
3. Set the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` so that the implicit conversion works.

While any of the options will work; you should use #1 and fix your table so the data is stored in the correct data type. If you really can't change the table then use #2 and ensure that your queries are comparing the same data types (and, if you need to, use explicit conversions between types). Option #3 is just there for completeness and is just going to allow you to continue using bad habits of relying on implicit type conversions; don't use it.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pPnOsGii)

Comment: Perfect point on *... continue using bad habits of relying on implicit type conversions; don't use it.*